# LINQ practice exercises or puzzles?

Tags: linq

I'm still trying to learn LINQ, though it's going more smoothly now that I've started to use it daily at work. I still don't feel *good* at it, though. Does anyone have any challenging practice exercises or puzzles I can use as a code-kata to improve my skills?

I'll leave this as community wiki, so maybe it can grow to a community list.

Answer (score 12):

If you have not discovered http://www.linqpad.net/ it lets you practice linq in a lightweight way, as well as having some inbuilt examples from C# 5.0 in  a nutshell and C# in Depth books.

Answer (score 8):

[101 Linq Samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/try-samples/101-linq-samples/) is a good one for reference. Not a puzzle though

Answer (score 2):

I know the 1st 2 questions at Project Euler is 'LINQ' friendly, I never did any more, but it should be fun either way  :)

Answer (score 1):

Puzzle:

Do a full outer join in LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

I've been finding "foreach's" in existing code and attempting to linq'ify them.  Many times things have been different enough for me to learn new concepts or at least if they're similar I get to feel more confident that my Linq skills are getting better.